# Producing images for Twitter

Tags: formatting, mactex, conversion, online, export

I would like a way of producing high quality images optimised for sharing on Twitter. These images would likely contain a mixture of equations, text, tables, etc.

Ideally the output produced after compiling would:

1. Produce an image in .png format;
2. Be transparent (that is, have no background);
3. Have a fixed width of 1024 pixels, and a *maximum* height of 1024;
4. Contain reasonable margins, so the maths/text isn't right on the border.

Keeping in mind, Twitter shrinks images down to a width of 506 pixels when displayed in the timeline. If possible I would like to avoid using the command line.

So far what I have is:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
paperwidth=506px,
paperheight=253px,
margin=0cm
}
\begin{document}
A \emph{group representation} is a group homomorphism
\[
    \rho \colon G \longrightarrow GL(V)
\]
from the group $G$ to the general linear group $GL(V)$. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked at `standalone`? What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @cfr You are right, I meant that I prefer to avoid the command line. I will edit question to clarify.

Comment: @cfr I have added what I have so far. Basically when I try and add a margin using geometry, standalone crops it back to no margin. I have no idea how to produce a transparent .png without resorting to the command line reflected in similar questions.

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed, as proposed in similar questions? And most importantly: what software (IDE) do you use to create LaTeX documents and compile them?

Comment: For standalone, add `border=5pt` or whatever to the class options.

Comment: @hbaderts According to the MacTex documentation "Convert from ImageMagick" is installed but nothing else. I use TexShop to create LaTeX documents and compile.

Comment: You only need `convert` or `gs`, depending on which you prefer. `standalone` can use either to convert the pages to images. (Or you could, in fact, use some other conversion utility, if you preferred, provided it can be used on the command line so you can pass it through to `standalone`.) Probably `standalone`'s default choices will do the job, so you may not even have to read the converters' documentation yourself.

Comment: You can't actually tell, but the PNG shown at the bottom of my answer is from `standalone` and is transparent. But SE seems to de-alpha it somehow. Actually, it is probably just the page ... ?

Comment: The PNG at the bottom of the page is definition transparent when I download it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`standalone` works OK if you read the documentation.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,preview,varwidth]{standalone}
\newenvironment{nothing}{}{}
\standaloneenv{nothing}
\begin{document}
\begin{nothing}
  A \emph{group representation} is a group homomorphism
  \[
  \rho \colon G \longrightarrow GL(V)
  \]
  from the group $G$ to the general linear group $GL(V)$.
\end{nothing}
\end{document}
```

[image: cropped sample]

You can then use `standalone`'s conversion facilities to convert the pages on-the-fly to the format of your choice. The conversion may use either ImageMagick's `convert` utility or `ghostscript`. See the manual for details of how to configure this through `standalone`.

The chances are good that

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,preview,varwidth,png]{standalone}
```

or

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,preview,varwidth,convert]{standalone}
```

will do what you want, but you can fine-tune the process if required.

Here's the result I get with `png`:

[image: transparent PNG]

Comment: This is great, thank you. I ended up using `\documentclass[border=10pt,preview,varwidth,convert={ghostscript}]{standalone}` as I didn

Comment: ...didn't have `convert` from ImageMagick installed after all. As for the size, is it better to adjust when converting or within the document itself?

Comment: In the document itself is better. Using the correct sized fonts, for example, will get better results than scaling a different sized font to size. (If you are using the default fonts or any others which provide different optical sizes.)